# Things to do after booting Kali Linux 2020.2 live usb persistence?

Tags: kali-linux, live-usb, persistence

I just wanted to know more about kali Linux because I strive to become a system admin in the future.

- I started to download kali-linux 2020.2 x64 live. I prefer to choose USB persistence because I mainly running my laptop on Windows OS.
- Im about to boot kali on my 8gb flash drive using Rufus and set persistence partition half of its size to 4gb. Everything works fine, I started with the terminal as usual, now testing persistence mode.
- I create

  ```
  mkdir folder1
  ```

  then create

  ```
  touch samplefile1
  ```

  and mv samplefile1 to `folder1`.
- I `sudo reboot` now. to reboot. Persistence mode is working because it saves the created directory with the file.
- I do know how to navigate to system files directories but have a little bit confusing.

That's all for what I have now because I don't know what to do next. please give me more advice about USB persistence.

Answer (score 1):

So, I understand that you are new to this system and are looking for some tutorials or exercises ideas?

If so, maybe look at [this beginner's guide at Cybrary](https://www.cybrary.it/blog/0p3n/kali-linux-a-beginners-guide/).

If you are completely new to Linux/Unix, Kali Linux is not for you. It is a system designed for penetration testing, with a bunch of specialized tools. Not usually used as a means of learning Linux, as you might find it hard. Maybe try Ubuntu, if that's the case.

If you are set on Kali and want to work on your pen-testing skills, there's a plethora of tutorials and courses available on the Internet,. 
Take for example [Cybrary](https://www.cybrary.it/) and search there as it is mostly free,
although it may require you to register.

Comment: We have ubuntu running on VM environment in my school. But I starting to love kali linux. Either Cracking or Penetration test isn't my interest yet.I look forward to dive in kali to understand the system and for managing network and security messure, to render denial of service attack.

Comment: Kal Linux is not meant to be a standalone system, it is more of a tool that you can for example start up in VM to perform some penetration testing etc. If you want to learn the system and manage network and security measures in Linux, then you should choose another one. But if you want to render a DDoS, this is something that Kali Linux can be useful for, however I wonder, what would be a target if such attack? How would you go about this?

Comment: I'm planning to use VM after I bought a new Laptop, It doesn't have enough RAM for my current machine to run Linux via VM, USB persistence is my option. Hmm yeah all of you guys have a good point about suggesting what's good for using Linux. Many people out there in Linux community advise that every Linux distro must need to understand well. A DDOS attack is a  famous method right? to mess up with the server until it goes down, It's pretty annoying for large companies.  Engineers will continue to find a way to prevent some new attacks. I will look forward to Cybrary very interesting.

Comment: a DDoS attack is a famous method of attacking companies networks, but not only is this annoying, but also very illegal. that's why I asked what do you have in mind when it comes to the target, because you might get in trouble if you try to do this

Comment: Indeed. Scan vulnerabilities using pentesting skill before they got your system, metasploit  is a good tool to use. Im not something to do about illegal things because dirty tricks isn't my style, definitely it won't fit my lifestyle.